# Passing image from one view to another

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm getting an image from the user from the photo gallery, and I want to pass it to a another view...

I've read that I should be able to simply do something like this:

```
secView.imgView.image = selectedImage.image;
```

Setting my UIImageView on the second view to be the image from my UIImageView...
But the UIImageView in the second view is just empty...

My code is this...

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *selectedImage;

    SecondView *secondView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *selectedImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SecondView *secondView;

-(IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)openGallery:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m (only the relevant parts)

```
-(IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender
{
    if(self.secondView == nil)
    {
        SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        self.secondView = secView;

        secView.imgView.image = selectedImage.image;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)openGallery:(id)sender
{
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    picker.delegate = self;

    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker 
{    
    [Picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker

didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{    
    // Save the image
    selectedImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [Picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In another post I read that another approach was to do this:

```
-(IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender
{
    if(self.secondView == nil)
    {
        SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        self.secondView = secView;

        [secView setImage:selectedImage.image];
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

and then in the secondview.h

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image;
```

and .m

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [imgView setImage:image];
}
```

But both approaches results in an empty UIImageView...
So what is the correct approach to doing this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

SecondView is fairly simple at the moment... (in the posted code I try and follow method two)

```
@interface SecondView : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *imgView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;

-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image;

@end

@implementation SecondView

@synthesize imgView;

-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [imgView setImage:image];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

**SOLUTION**
Okay... Went back to the first method and made some alterations which ultimately worked...

```
-(IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender
{
    if(self.secondView == nil)
    {
        SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        self.secondView = secView;

        secView.theImage = selectedImage.image;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

And in the secondView, I created UIImage *theImage - then I set [imgView setImage:theImage]; in viewDidLoad, which worked...

Comment: please put the code of class SecondView

Comment: It's been added now :) But I had already shown the only addition in the code apart from the standard... (please note, the secondView posted is where I try the second method mentioned...)

Comment: Thank you! Passing UIImage vs UIImageView from the original view controller to the secondViewController worked for me as well.  Maybe because UIImageView on the secondVC was an IBOutlet it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
-(IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender
{
    if(self.secondView == nil)
    {
        SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        self.secondView = secView;

        secView.theImage = selectedImage.image;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

SecondView:

```
@interface SecondView : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *imgView;
    UIImage *theImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *theImage;

-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image;

@end
```

and in the .m of secondView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [imgView setImage:theImage];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem :

In your class secondView, your UIImageView is not connected to the object UIImageView in the nib file.

You should have something like that :

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
```

To check if the view is correctly connected to the Nib you can do this :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Your problem is interesting please let me know if it doesn't work I'll check deeper.

Comment: Actually, I create the IBOutlet in the @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView; :) so that's not the error... unfortunately :) just to be sure, I added the code to change the backgroundcolor, which worked...

Comment: Oups I didn't see it. I'll check little deeper :)

Comment: Are you sure your selectedImage.image != nil?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be... When I finish picking an image from the gallery, I set: selectedImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; ...

Comment: Yes, but maybe it's not returning the correct image. You can try to change the color in the sendImage:(id)sender method to see if you can access. It's little hard to check your code without testing stuff :)

Comment: Hm... If I add: secView.imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; in sendImage, nothing happens in the secondView... the UIImageView doesn't change color... so it seems like it's not being run properly... so the image is probably not being set correctly as well... But I'm not sure how to fix that

Comment: Hm... Got something to work... I'll update my question with the solution

Comment: Nice :) I want to see that I'struggling on that too for 20 min ^^

Answer (score 0):

First Viewcontroller:

```
-(void)passimage
{
    Second_ViewController *select_main = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second_ViewController"];
    select_main.tt_image = _bg_imageview.image;
    [[self navigationController]  pushViewController:select_main animated:YES];
}
```

Second Viewcontroller pass UIImage object:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    _bg_imageview.image = _bb_image;
}
```