# Storyboard passing Images between views

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uiimageview

I'm trying to pass an image from one view to another. I have a camera button and when press fires off the uiimagepickercontroller. Once the image is selected the edit photo screen is pushed onto the screen. Whenever the screen loads nothing appears. I tried following this post [Passing image from one view to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496652/passing-image-from-one-view-to-another) but it seems not to work.

Here is my code for the first view controller:

firstViewController.h

```
@interface firstViewController : UITableViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>

- (IBAction)cameraButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

firstViewController.m

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        ECDEditViewController *viewController = [[ECDEditViewController alloc] initWithImage:image];

        UINavigationController *composeController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showCompose"];
        //[self.navigationController presentViewController:composeController animated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:composeController animated:YES];

    }];

}
```

secondViewController.h

```
@interface ECDEditViewController : UITableViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)aImage;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

secondViewController.m

@implementation ECDEditViewController
@synthesize myImage;
@synthesize image;


- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)aImage {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (!aImage) {
            NSLog(@"sorry no picture loaded®");
            return nil;
        }
        self.image = aImage;
        [myImage setImage:aImage];
        NSLog(@"picture loaded");
   }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"im trying");

    [myImage setImage:image];
    [myImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
}
```

[image]

Comment: If "myImage" is UIImageView, remove code using it from -initWithImage: - your view isn't loaded, so you can't talk to it. Step through debugger and see that it's nil. The ECDEditViewController you instantiate never seems to get presented. Whereas you seem to be pushing one navigation controller ("composeController") onto another navigation controller, which is at best strange, and probably wrong.

Comment: What is composeController? Don't you want to pass the image to ECDEditViewController?

Comment: @rdelmar thats the storyboard ID I gave it

Comment: The ID you gave what? You question isn't clear. ECDEditViewController is a UITableViewController subclass, but you're saying that composeController is a UINavigationController. Are these two different things?

Comment: my question have nothing to do with the view controllers, it's passing the image from one view to another @rdelmar

Comment: Really? What you show in your image is two view controllers. Are you trying to get an image from the one on the left to the image view you show in the right hand controller (the one that says "Edit View Controller" at the bottom)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34299/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-eric-oboite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info { 

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ 

UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; 

ECDEditViewController *composeController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showCompose"]; 
composeController.image = image; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:composeController animated:YES]; 

}]; 

}
```

Your composeController is actually an ECDEditViewController, not a UINavigationController. So this line is unnecessary (as is the initWithImage: method):

```
 ECDEditViewController *viewController = [[ECDEditViewController alloc] initWithImage:image];
```