# How to pass image from one page to another in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to pass image from one page to another by selecting image from gallery or using camera.whe user click on display button image will be tranfered to next page
i have tried this. but not working in .m file

```
 @interface ImagePicker () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
    UIImageView *fordisplay;
}
@end

@implementation ImagePicker

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)clickOnDate:(id)sender
{
    datePicker *date=[[datePicker alloc]initWithNibName:@"datePicker" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:date animated:YES];
}
-(IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
-(IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
   DisplayImage *obj_display1=[[DisplayImage alloc]initWithNibName:@"DisplayImage" bundle:nil];

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //self.imageview.image = chosenImage;
    imageview.image=chosenImage;
     obj_display1.imageDisplayy=chosenImage;**
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
-(IBAction)display:(id)sender
{
    DisplayImage *obj_display=[[DisplayImage alloc]initWithNibName:@"DisplayImage" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_display animated:YES];
}
```

and in next page where want to display image

.h file

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *imageDisplayy;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize imageDisplayy;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    obj_imageview.image=imageDisplayy;


}
```

Comment: i know this may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496652/passing-image-from-one-view-to-another. but i am not getting..

Comment: Pass nsdata insted of passing image directly
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
and for displaying image use
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

Comment: But i want to choose photo from gallary or capturing it. how i make global variable that can  access the selected or chosen image.

Comment: @bro same as you did for uiimage, use nsdata by property synthesize it

Comment: does it help, or need code

Comment: Doesnot working. as data on choose and capture button is local, how to make that selected image as global for transfer.

Comment: ok let me explain, in your DisplayImage controller  add
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSData *data;
and sysnthesise it

Comment: now in your current controller from where you are picking image 
-(IBAction)display:(id)sender
{
    DisplayImage *obj_display=[[DisplayImage alloc]initWithNibName:@"DisplayImage" bundle:nil];
UIImage *img = imageview.image;
    NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    objWebViewController.data =data1;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_display animated:YES];
}

Comment: and finally in your display controller use 
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
    yourImageview.image= image;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103095/discussion-between-narendra-pandey-and-vijay-palwe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an instance of DisplayImage in your this method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

While performing navigation you are creating another new instance which doesn't have imageDisplayy property set for it.

```
-(IBAction)display:(id)sender
{
    DisplayImage *obj_display=[[DisplayImage alloc]initWithNibName:@"DisplayImage" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_display animated:YES];
}
```

One solution for this problem is make DisplayImage *obj_display1 as property in your ImagePicker.

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) DisplayImage *obj_display1;
```

Instantiate it in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.obj_display1=[[DisplayImage alloc]initWithNibName:@"DisplayImage" bundle:nil];
}
```

update code in this method as

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
//self.imageview.image = chosenImage;
imageview.image=chosenImage;
 self.obj_display1.imageDisplayy=chosenImage;**
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Then perform navigation

```
-(IBAction)display:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.obj_display1 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: actually user select or choose photo from it's gallary or camera. i want to transfer that selected photo into next page.

Comment: yes try the code I have written for you. It will work for you. See this method 

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

Answer (score 0):

Your are directly passing image to imagview.Instead of that pass image from one view controller to anorther.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
   DisplayImage *obj_display1=[[DisplayImage alloc]initWithNibName:@"DisplayImage" bundle:nil];

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //self.imageview.image = chosenImage;
    imageview.image=chosenImage;
     obj_display1.imageDisplayy=chosenImage;**
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

next page where want to display image

.h file

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIImage *imageDisplayy;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize imageDisplayy;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    obj_imageview.image=imageDisplayy;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
//In .h file 
// change your property to UIImage instead of imageview

    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImage *imageDisplayy;
```